# variables de un array con mismo nombre

Tags: java, json, array, variables

Poseo 2 arrays en Java con nombre diferente de Array (sender y recipient), pero las variables dentro de los arrays son las mismas (account_number, product_id, external_id, simulation, recipient_sms_notification, sender_sms_notification), al declararlas debo de llamar a las variables dentro del los arrays, como hago para llamarla y se sepa distinguir entre ambas?

```
String message;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("account_number",account_number);
json.put("product_id", product_id);
json.put("external_id", external_id);
json.put("simulation", simulation);
json.put("recipient_sms_notification", recipient_sms_notification);
json.put("sender_sms_notification", sender_sms_notification);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("last_name", last_name);
item.put("middle_name", middle_name);
item.put("first_name", first_name);
item.put("email", email);
item.put("mobile", mobile);

array.put(item);
json.put("sender", array);

JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item2 = new JSONObject();
item.put("last_name", last_name);
item.put("middle_name", middle_name);
item.put("first_name", first_name);
item.put("email", email);
item.put("mobile", mobile);
array.put(item);
json.put("recipient", array);

message = json.toString();
```

Comment: Veo que tienes un problema aquí: `json.put("recipient", array);`, creo que debería ser `json.put("recipient", array2);`, lo mismo con el segundo `array.put(item);`, debería ser `array2.put(item2);` y todos los `item.put(...)` que están después de la declaración de `item2`.

Comment: Gracias Por la Observacion! pero sigo con las variables.. como hago para que al llamar a first_name me lo tome como la variable de sender e igual recipient con first_name?

Comment: Para un JSON, esas variables son diferentes, sin importar que tengan el mismo valor. Solo puedes hacer el mejor esfuerzo para asegurarte que al momento de crear los datos, dichas variables contengan el mismo valor. El consumidor del cliente será responsable de mantener eso y utilizarlo adecuadamente.

Comment: Es decir, si las declaro asi no hay problema?
public static void aprovisionar(String simulation, String recipient_sms_notification, String sender_sms_notification, String account_number, String external_id, String product_id, String sender, String last_name, String middle_name, String first_name, String email, String mobile,String recipient)

No hay problema? o me equivoco?

Comment: En su lugar, mejor definiría `public void aprovisionar(String simulation, SMSRecipient recipient, SMSSender sender);` y así ahorrar los parámetros y lanzar excepciones tipo `IllegalArgumentException` si las variables no están completas (no utilices métodos estáticos a menos que crees clases utilitarias).

Comment: Entiendo, pero las variables debo declararlas asi, explico esa parte.. enviare datos a un Web service y el espera recibir esos datos de la manera que menciono, no puedo alterarlas de ninguna manera. Por eso mi pregunta en la parte de los array, simplemente con declararlas como envie en el mensaje anterior es suficiente o en necesario declararla de otra manera mis variables para los arrays?

Comment: El servicio web externo tiene su diseño, el diseño de tu aplicación sigue **tu** diseño. Al llamar a tu servicio web, puedes utilizar `recipient.getDato1(), recipient.getDato2() ...` y así. Que el servicio web tenga un diseño extraño no significa que tus aplicaciones también deban tenerlo. Y sobre tu pregunta: las variables son diferentes y punto, si **sus valores** deben ser iguales, solo debes asegurarte que antes de llamar al servicio web estás enviando el mismo **valor** en las **diferentes** variables.

Answer (score 1):

Te comento que Java es un lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos, por lo tanto, el enfoque correcto es crear una clase `Sender` y una clase `Recipient` con sus respectivos atributos, incluso si tienen atributos en común, deberías crear una tercera clase "padre" de la cual hereden `Sender` y `Recipient`. Luego simplemente creas Arrays de `Sender` y `Recipient` y llamas sus atributos como corresponda. Pero tu problema lo puedes solucionar como sigue:

```
JSONArray senderArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject senderDetail = new JSONObject();
senderDetail.put("sender.last_name", last_name);
senderDetail.put("sender.middle_name", middle_name);
senderDetail.put("sender.first_name", first_name);
senderDetail.put("sender.email", email);
senderDetail.put("sender.mobile", mobile);
senderArray.put(senderDetail);
json.put("sender", senderArray);

JSONArray recipientArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject recipientDetail = new JSONObject();
recipientDetail.put("recipient.last_name", last_name);
recipientDetail.put("recipient.middle_name", middle_name);
recipientDetail.put("recipient.first_name", first_name);
recipientDetail.put("recipient.email", email);
recipientDetail.put("recipient.mobile", mobile);
recipientArray.put(recipient.recipientDetail);
json.put("recipient", recipientArray);

message = json.toString();
```